# Remove " " from String in robotframework

Tags: string, robotframework

My code is,

```
*** Variables ***

    ${sample}       2000, 2002, 2050, 2010-2020

*** Test Cases ***

MyFirstTest 

    ${num}=         evaluate       '${result}'.replace('"','')
    [Setup]  Create Service   Test  ${sample}  ${pub_mail}
```

[image]

This is the actual result. I'm tryin to pass more than one numbers instead of one single number. But I'm getting " " in my result. How to resolve it?

[image]

Comment: your code seems to work perfectly fine for me, are you sure the result is a string?

Comment: You're likely only seeing the quotes in the log. They probably aren't actually in the data.

Comment: Yes. In my local editor, I didn't see the " ". But while I execute it, I got an error like this. It shows " " because it is a string value. I have to pass more than one number in the same format which I mentioned in my code.

Comment: I have tried with list and tuple also. It contains () and [] . So that also not getting pass

Comment: The quotes, () and [] are not part of your actual data/value  - they are part of String representation of your data .. Like @BryanOakley said.  Those extra characters are there because when data is printed, python will call `__repr__()` of the variable which will make the value of your data more "human readable" ..

Answer (score 1):

The reason you can't remove the quotes is that the data doesn't contain any quotes. When you see quotes, this is just how python displays lists, tuples, and dicts when printed out. In the actual data there are no quotes.